# How to convert XML file in UTF-8 using Groovy builder StreamingMarkupBuilder

Tags: xml, grails, utf-8, groovy, markupbuilder

Even if the question subject seems complicated, the issue is quite simple.

I create an XML file with the following script:

```
def xmlFile = new File("file-${System.currentTimeMillis()}.xml")
mb = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
mb.encoding = "UTF-8"
new FileWriter(xmlFile) << mb.bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    out << "\n"
    someMarkup {}
}
```

Then when I parse this file using code like:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlFile)
```

I got the following `MalformedByteSequenceException` exception:

> Exception thrown: Invalid byte 2 of
>   3-byte UTF-8 sequence

And if I convert the file in UTF-8 format (using Notepad++ for instance) then everything is ok.

So, what can I do to save my file in UTF-8 format? Why the code `mb.encoding = "UTF-8"` does not do it?

Thx

Comment: You can refer to this blog. http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-creating-xml-with.html it should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap an output stream writer around a FileOutputStream is utf-8 is not the default charset

```
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(exportXmlFile),'utf-8') << mb.bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    out << "\n"
    someMarkup {}
}
```

I'm not sure what setting mb.encoding does, probably just sets the charset in the xml header